# In Python multiple inheritance, how bad is it for parent class to use child defined variables?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

```
class BaseOne(object):

    def base_one(self):
        print self.first
        print self.second
        # Do stuffs with self.first and self.second defined from sub class


class BaseTwo(object):

    def base_two(self):
        print self.first
        print self.second
        # Do stuffs with self.first and self.second defined from sub class


class Stackoverflow(BaseOne, BaseTwo):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Stackoverflow, self).__init__()
        self.first = 'Stack'
        self.second = 'Overflow'


class Serverfault(BaseOne, BaseTwo):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Serverfault, self).__init__()
        self.first = 'Server'
        self.second = 'Fault'

Stackoverflow().base_one()
Serverfault().base_one()
```

In either `BaseOne` or `BaseTwo`, I want to use variables defined from the sub class.  Is there a better way to do the above?

Comment: you may want to take a look at abc http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html as it seems you're making an abstract base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason not to do this.  I would suggest adding something like `first, second = None, None` on the base classes (or creating an even higher level that those two inherit from) to account for a case where a subclass failed to set those values, but otherwise this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as abstract classes in other languages. No reason not to do this. Except you might be muddying the water here - make sure your code stays understandable.

I would probably:

```
class BaseOne(object):
    def base_one(self):
        print self.first()
        print self.second()

    def first(self):
        return "bad boy, don't call this on abstract instance"

    def second(self):
        return 'really, son, you have a problem here. Go create some instances of subclasses!'
```